# Derived column which contains the column names sorted by date

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I want to create a derived column like shown below without using `If-Else` statements.

[image]

I have the columns `x,y,z` which are all dates. I want to get a fourth column which shows the order of the fields in `ascending` without using `If-Else or Case when`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample data I guess the 3d row result is `'z,y,x'` right?

```
select xyz.*, t.derived_column from (
  select s_n, group_concat(type order by value) as derived_column from 
  ( 
    select s_n, 'x' as type, x as value from xyz
    union all
    select s_n, 'y' as type, y as value from xyz
    union all
    select s_n, 'z' as type, z as value from xyz
  ) as xyz1  
  group by s_n
  ) as t
inner join xyz
on t.s_n = xyz.s_n
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hTqm2JBuwgn4NVHrkRut1M/2)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this without aggregation is rather tricky.  But it is possible.  Of course, the real challenge is getting the middle element -- particularly without `case` or `if()`.  However, that is just a challenge.

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 highest,
                 coalesce(elt(field('x', highest, least) + 1, 'x'), elt(field('y', highest, least) + 1, 'y'), elt(field('z', highest, least) + 1, 'z')),
                 lowest
                )
from (select x.*,
             elt(field(greatest(x, y, z), x, y, z), 'x', 'y', 'z') as highest,
             elt(field(least(x, y, z), x, y, z), 'x', 'y', 'z') as least
      from (select 'a' as a, 1 as x, 2 as y, 3 as z union all
            select 'b' as a, 4 as x, 2 as y, 3 as z
           ) t
     ) t;
```

You can actually express the middle value expression without a subquery, but it is much more complicated.  The above uses integers, but the logic works just as well with dates or strings.

This can also be written as:

```
select elt(field(concat(highest, lowest), 'xy', 'xz', 'yz', 'yx', 'zx', 'zy'), 'x,z,y', 'x,y,z', 'y,x,z', 'y,z,x', 'z,y,x', 'z,x,y')
from (select t.*,
             elt(field(greatest(x, y, z), x, y, z), 'x', 'y', 'z') as highest,
             elt(field(least(x, y, z), x, y, z), 'x', 'y', 'z') as lowest
      from (select 'a' as a, 1 as x, 2 as y, 3 as z union all
            select 'b' as a, 4 as x, 2 as y, 3 as z
           ) t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

For each of the `x`, `y`, `z` columns select the corresponding character literal, the column alias to a common name and the other columns as they are. Union the results. Now select the other columns from the union and use `group_concat()` with an `ORDER BY` expression to get the sorted list.

```
SELECT x.s_n,
       x.x,
       x.y,
       x.z,
       group_concat(x.c
                    ORDER BY x.d) derived_column
       FROM (SELECT t.s_n,
                    t.x,
                    t.y,
                    t.z,
                    'x' c,
                    t.x d
                    FROM elbat t
             UNION ALL
             SELECT t.s_n,
                    t.x,
                    t.y,
                    t.z,
                    'y' c,
                    t.y d
                    FROM elbat t
             UNION ALL
             SELECT t.s_n,
                    t.x,
                    t.y,
                    t.z,
                    'z' c,
                    t.z d
                    FROM elbat t) x
       GROUP BY x.s_n,
                x.x,
                x.y,
                x.z;
```